# syscall in ROP gadget chain not running

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, system-calls, exploit

I'm trying to call execve("/bin/cat", "filename" , NULL) via a chain of ROP gadget
I'm able to step through the syscall but no output or error is shown so I'm not sure what is the problem

Using gdb, this is the last gadget in the ROP chain. I can only find call gs without ret, but i think it should be ok

```
(gdb) x/20i $pc
=> 0xf7dfb8ae:  call   *%gs:0x10
   0xf7dfb8b5:  pop    %ebx
   0xf7dfb8b6:  ret    
   0xf7dfb8b7:  lea
```

```
(gdb) info registers
eax            0xb                 11
ecx            0xffffde1a          -8678
edx            0xffffde19          -8679
ebx            0xffffde11          -8687
esp            0xffffde60          0xffffde60
ebp            0xffffde48          0xffffde48
esi            0xf7fbb000          -134500352
edi            0xf7fbb000          -134500352
eip            0xf7dfb8ae          0xf7dfb8ae
eflags         0x202               [ IF ]
cs             0x23                35
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x2b                43
es             0x2b                43
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x63                99
```

```
(gdb) x/s $ebx
0xffffde11: "/bin/cat"
(gdb) x/s $ecx
0xffffde1a: "/home/victim/flag.txt"
(gdb) x/s $edx
0xffffde19: ""
```

Below are the arguments with null-terminated

```
(gdb) x /32x $ebx
0xffffde11: 0x2f    0x62    0x69    0x6e    0x2f    0x63    0x61    0x74
0xffffde19: 0x00    0x2f    0x68    0x6f    0x6d    0x65    0x2f    0x76
0xffffde21: 0x69    0x63    0x74    0x69    0x6d    0x2f    0x66    0x6c
0xffffde29: 0x61    0x67    0x2e    0x74    0x78    0x74    0x00    0x00
```

Thank you

Comment: Use `strace` instead of gdb to see what system call, if any, is attempted.

Comment: You should be able to step into the call and see if 1) the call actually lands in the vSDO (it's unlikely but make sure glibc already initialized `gs:0x10`) and 2) the arguments are still valid (I see the strings are below the stack pointer but they should be enough far away to survive until `sysenter` and then the stack is switched). You can also see what error the system call returns.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jester's comment above of using `strace`, I have been able to debug the parameters being passed to `execve`